# TypeScript, undefined value to concrete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

How do I get from a potentially undefined value to something I can assign to state?  I know the data is there but I can't disable the typescript error by doing a check first.

I'm trying to put staleModes into state so I can render controls for each item:

```
const temps = useSelector((state: RootState) => selectTemps(selectSlss(state)));

const proposedStates = temps?.proposedStates;

const staleModes = proposedStates?.map(a => a.stale.mode);

const [proposedListStale, setProposedListStale] = useState<string[]>(staleModes);
```

It complains on staleModes here: useState<string[]>(staleModes);

Error is:
Argument of type '(string | undefined)[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string[] | (() => string[])'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string[] | (() => string[])'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optional chaining may result in `staleModes` being assigned `undefined`. If you really need the optional chaining because the property may not exist, you can alternate with the empty array.

Since `mode` may also be `undefined`, alternate it with the empty string:

```
const staleModes = proposedStates?.map(a => a.stale.mode ?? '') ?? [];
```

But if you're sure the properties and data exists, then remove the optional chaining and use type assertion instead:

```
const temps = useSelector((state: RootState) => selectTemps(selectSlss(state)))!;

const staleModes = temps.proposedStates!.map(a => a.stale.mode);
```

Comment: The optional chaining is the only way I can assign proposedStates.  It requires it to not say that temps is possibly null.
Neither of those methods changed the type of staleModes, it's still const storeModels: (string | undefined)[] and can't be assigned in "useState<string[]>(staleModes)"

Comment: Are you sure that the `.mode` property contains a string, and not `undefined`?

Comment: Mode can be undefined: (property) BaseReComponent.mode?: string | undefined
 
Am I able to assign a default to empty string somehow?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same technique in the `.map`: `a.stale.mode ?? ''`

Comment: Thank you!  I hadn't seen that technique.  I'm an old dev learning React with typescript and it's painful.